# Something like Mockito's Answer for Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spock

In Mockito there is nice method for programatic answers from interactions with mocks. E.g. we can program mock to return parameter which was passed to it's method call:

```
when(mockDao.persist(any(Entity.class)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Entity>() {

    public Entity answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        Entity entity = (Entity) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];

        return entity;
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do the same in Spock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mockDao.persist(_) >> { it[0] }
```

Or, with destructuring:

```
mockDao.persist(_) >> { Entity entity -> entity }
```